How to create PySpark column of dictionary type with value not of any fixed type?
This is a pyspark code. I am creating two columns, 'item' and 'properties'.
'item' column is of String type and 'properties' column is of dictionary type where the type of key is String but the type of value is not fixed. How do I implement this?
Here I have written value type of Integer, but I require that value be of any type. What type should I use for that?
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, MapType, IntegerType

schema = StructType([
    StructField('item', StringType(), True),
    StructField('properties', MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()),True)
])

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkExample').getOrCreate()
dataDictionary = [
        ('Eraser',{'cost':1,'color':'white'}),
        ('Pencil',{'cost':2,'color':'Blue'}),
        ('Pen',{'cost':3,'color':'black'}),
        ('Color',{'cost':4,'color':'grey'}),
        ('Paper',{'cost':5,'color':''})
        ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=dataDictionary, schema = schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)


There is no datatype in Spark SQL that corresponds to a generic object type, i.e., no ObjectType. You may store arbitrary values as their string representation and perform conversion as needed.

@HristoIliev - you should make this an answer imo.  The only thing worth adding is you cannot dynamically convert to or from types at runtime, the spark query plan requires fixed types with all expressions from_yaml for example needs to require the ddl to be fixed - it cannot be another field and change across the dataframe.
